lld cannot open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 in cross compiling situation
I am using Clang++ to do cross-compilation from x86_64-pc-windows-msvc to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.
The demo program is just a C++ Hello World program, using iostream.
To provide Linux env on my Windows host machine, I copied the env(header files, .a, .so, ...) from WSL2 to the host.
You can see the command I used in the Powershell and the output, my lld linker cannot open this libm.so.6 dynamic library.
The C:/wsl2/ is the folder I created to store the Linux env which is copied manually from wsl2.
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\cmake_demo\simple> clang++ --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --sysroot="C:/wsl2" -o main ./main.cpp -fuse-ld=lld -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

ld.lld: error: cannot open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: no such file or directory
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I met a "similar" issue for libc_nonshared.a, in that time, I copy the relevant .a file from wsl2 to host Linux env and it works.
Unfortunately, this time this method doesn't work, I tried to copy libm.so.6 to C:/wsl2 folder. You can see that they are not symbol links cuz their Length are not 0.
PS C:\wsl2\usr\lib> ls C:\wsl2\usr\aarch64-linux-gnu\lib | findstr libm
-a----         2/23/2022  12:26 PM        1445378 libm.a
-a----         2/23/2022  12:26 PM         551064 libm.so
-a----         4/16/2024   3:40 PM         940560 libm.so.6
    Directory: C:\wsl2\usr\aarch64-linux-gnu\lib
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         4/16/2024   3:40 PM         940560 libm.so.6
    Directory: C:\wsl2\usr\lib
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         4/16/2024   3:40 PM         940560 libm.so.6
    Directory: C:\wsl2\usr\lib\x86_64-linux-gnu
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         4/16/2024   3:40 PM         940560 libm.so.6
    Directory: C:\wsl2\usr\lib64\x86_64-linux-gnu
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         4/16/2024   3:40 PM         940560 libm.so.6

I guess this is because of lacking of the dynamic linker on the Windows platform. (.a are static libs but .so seems to be dynamic libs) After adding -v option in Clang++, the output with more details is listed below:
...
 C:/wsl2/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 C:/wsl2/usr/include
End of search list.
 "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\ld.lld" --sysroot=C:/wsl2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 
        -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
        -o main "C:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../..\\crt1.o" 
                "C:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../..\\crti.o" 
                "C:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11\\crtbegin.o" 
        -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
        -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 
        -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib64 
        -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib/../lib64 
        -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../lib64 
        -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../.. 
        -LC:/wsl2/usr/lib "C:\\Users\\hzhang3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\main-61818f.o" 
        -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc "C:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11\\crtend.o" "C:/wsl2/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../..\\crtn.o"
ld.lld: error: cannot open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: no such file or directory
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
...

I notice that /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 are assigned to ld.lld as dynamic linker, which is a Unix dynamic linker.
It's not very suprising that ld.lld try to find and cannot find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 this Unix-like stuff on my Windows host machine.
I have several questions to discuss here:

Is that really stupid to cross-compile from Windows to Linux with clang++?

Which dynamic linker should be used in this case? Cuz it seems impossible to use Linux dynamic linker on Windows host machine. (path incorrect and dynamic linker doesn't exist)

How can I hack the lld and let it by-pass this strange dynamic linker so that it can find the stuff it needs on the specific path (where libm.so.6 is placed)?

When doing cross-compilation from Windows to Linux x64, which Linux env is recommanded? I tried Cygwin but I cannot install certain libs through its setup application. It seems that Cygwin is an env used to build native Windows application (AKA from Linux to Windows).



-dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 looks fine to me, this path should only be used at runtime. The real problem is LLD searching for libm at the wrong location, not sure what's going on.

This issue is fixed by replacing libm.so with libm.so.6.
Although the linker says libm.so.6 is not found, the real file it looks for is libm.so.
BTW, using a Ubuntu docker image helps simplify the library structure and avoid messing up with useless files such as drivers(if you only want to compile a Hello world program) when installing a Linux env.
That's the way how I do, not using heavy wsl2.

"replacing libm.so with libm.so.6" What do you mean "replacing"?

Hello, it means: cp ./libm.so.6 ./libm.so, AKA overwriting it with libm.so.6

Ah, this is because there originally was a symlink from libm.so to libm.so.6, and you lost it when copying files from Linux to Windows?

Yes, exactly:), symlink is troubling when I install the env in this way.
